# Can't remove ice tray from GE french door fridge

Tags: refrigerator

I have a GE stainless french door fridge model GFSS6KKXSS. I can't get the ice maker tray to come out. It has a small release lever on the side, which I have used before when removing it. It seems to be frozen in there, or stuck on something.

I want to take it out because it was jammed and the auger wouldn't turn. I blew into the ice depensing hole with a hair dryer and got it to turn again. It dispense the ice, but I need to get it out to see if anything is broken. Disclaimer: Not a photo of my actual fridge - stock photo used.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

DO NOT use a hair dryer in your fridge.  I've seen it many times where people destroy the fridge because they get the plastic too hot and it will actually melt.

If you have a big cooler, load it up with all of your stuff, turn the fridge off and leave the door open.  This should melt any ice that is stuck there.  If you leave the freezer closed and don't open it, don't worry about taking your stuff out of it. It'll stay cold for quite a while on it's own.